# How to deploy to users an Excel file containing openpyxl code?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

How can I help user to use an excel file I've created with openpyxl code in without they have to install manually openpyxl?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Freeze your code with [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

First, install PyInstaller with pip:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Windows:
Open a command prompt or PowerShell and cd to your folder containing your script.
Write the following and press Enter:

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py
```

You can find the frozen exe from the dist folder.